# Why onchange function not working with semantic class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I using reactjs and semantic ui and want to call a OnChange function on input checkbox:

**App.js**

```
getChecked = (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked === true){
        this.setState({
            rent: '1'
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            rent: '0'
        });
    }
    console.log(e);
};

..

<Input onChange={this.getChecked} type="checkbox" name="isRent" id="isRent" value={this.state.rent}/>
```

This code working perfectly **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e97kh6xn/)**

But when I use checkbox class from semantic ui on this input, onChange function not working anymore **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e97kh6xn/2/)**

**Before:**

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.getChecked}/>
```

**After:**

```
<div className="ui slider checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.getChecked}/>
</div>
```

Any idea for why it now working?

Comment: You are mixing jQuery with react, this line is messing it up `$('.checkbox').checkbox();` probably jQuery adding its own handler to it and so ignoring you function. Don't use jQuery anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when semantic ui classes is applied, `input` get z-index value of -1. (try inspecting it).
So, now `input` never gets clicked, hence `onChange` function is not invoked.

What you could do this, make the `checkbox` **controlled**.

```
  state = { checked: false }
  toggle = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ checked: !prevState.checked }))

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui slider checkbox" onClick={this.toggle}>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```